# How do I disable Chrome from timing out / killing a tab?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, google-chrome, timeout

A user is reporting that a certain screen of our Flex app times out in Google Chrome and IE. I can reproduce this problem, but I don't know what is causing it. I cannot reproduce it with Firefox.

I was wondering if there is a way to temporarily disable this feature in Chrome because I know that in Firefox(at least in v3.6) when a Flex/Flash app executes for too long I get a stack trace from the Flash runtime pointing me to the problem. example:

```
Error: Error #1502: A script has executed for longer than the default timeout period of 15 seconds.
    at TimeoutTest/___TimeoutTest_Button1_click()[/TimeoutTest/src/TimeoutTest.mxml:5]
```

I think that Chrome is hijacking this process and denying me that information, so I would prefer to prevent this behavior for now to see if the runtime will detect the timeout and provide a similar trace.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm coming late but the answer is in Chrome menu (the three stripes): Go to settings -> Show Advanced settings -> Privacy: uncheck the option that says 'Predict network actions to improve page load performance'. Hope that helps.

Comment: that option doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Go to the publish settings -> Flash in your main Fla and change the Script time limt parameter. Hope it works

Comment: I am in Flex and while there is a scriptTimeoutLimit you can set at the Application level I have found that it is not strictly enforced. I am looking for a way to disable Chrome from timing out a tab.

Comment: I did some looking around like i am sure that you did they said that its a flaw within the system. http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6c0b3850c0e57bb2&hl=en says that a lot of people had to reinstall it and or pull the tap out into a new window for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? The normal script limit is 15 seconds I believe. If one of your users is getting those errors that means your application is hanging for more than 15 seconds!

If that's the case, you're looking about this the wrong way. Instead of just removing the script limit, try to find out what's causing so much delay and try to optimize it. The [Flex Profiler](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=profiler_3.html) will help tremendously.

Comment: Thanks -- I am aware of everything that you are saying and I may have to resort to the profiler. Just wanted to find out if anyone is aware of a way to disable the feature in Chrome. I am not trying to find out how to disable the feature for all users, just myself in this particular instance as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Chrome Browser Shortcut on the Desktop. Right Click the shortcut, Select Properties, Under Target, Add `--disable-hang-monitor` to the end, like so: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-hang-monitor`. Apply Changes. Open the shortcut if you want to remove the script time-out, otherwise use normal link. All browsers have to be closed before reopening the shortcut.